# How to get highest row number using query?

Tags: java, android

I have an sqlitedb, row _id auto increments. How do I form a query to get the highest number in row _id and put that into a variable? I know how to do it in sql but not using the query method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered elsewhere on this site:

```
String query = "SELECT MAX(row_id) AS max_id FROM mytable";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
int id = 0;     
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{               
  id = cursor.getInt(0);                         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor Days = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{"_id"},
                "_id="+"(select max(_id) from" +DATABASE_TABLE+")" , null, null, null, null, null);
```

This should also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("row_id"))
```

Did you try this? When you insert the data in database, autoincrement increases the id for primary key and I assume row_id must be your one of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

you can get this by count and also by using MAX(column name) function in your query.
max function returns the maximum value

Answer (score 0):

```
        Cursor newCursor = newContentResolver.query
        (
            CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[]{"_id"}, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null
        );

        if(newCursor.moveToLast()) 
        {
            int index = newCursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
            String id = newCursor.getString(index);     
            Log.v("TAG", "Highest id : "+id);       
        }
```

- This is one way of getting the highest row id. Since the generation is auto increment, we are assured that the last row is the highest in the database. moveToLast() moves the cursor to the last row.